# Rails, linking of pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested, ruby-on-rails-5

I would need some help with this please.

I have «  contenders » that belongs to posts. (each post has different contenders).

I would like to be able to display the contenders when I click on a certain post.

I don’t know how to link/route this. I’d like to have « posts » as my index page and be able to click on any post and have the corresponding contenders.
I added a post_id to contenders as a reference. But I don’t even know if that was the right thing to do.

Thanks for your help!!

PS: I don’t know if that changes anything but I’m trying to use ActiveAdmin as a backend and Carrierwave to upload image.

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Your poll app</h1>
            </div>
            <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <%= post.name %>
                    <br>
                    <%= post.id %>
                    <%= link_to "Contenders", post_contenders_path(post.id) %>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="">
                     <%= image_tag post.image_url %>
                    </img>
                </a>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
</div>
```

**contenders/index.html.erb**

```
class ContendersController < InheritedResources::Base
     def index
        @contenders = Contender.all
     end

     def new
        @contender = Contender.new
     end

     def create
        @contender = Contender.new(post_params)

        if @contender.save
           redirect_to posts_path, notice: "The contender #{@contender.name} has been uploaded."
        else
           render "new"
        end

     end

     def destroy
        @contender = contender.find(params[:id])
        @contender.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path, notice:  "The post #{@contender.name} has been deleted."
     end

      private
         def post_params
         params.require(:contender).permit(:name, :image)
      end

    private

      def contender_params
        params.require(:contender).permit(:name, :image, :post_id)
      end
end
```

**controllers/contenders_controllers.rb**

```
class ContendersController < InheritedResources::Base
     def index
        @contenders = Contender.all
     end

     def new
        @contender = Contender.new
     end

     def create
        @contender = Contender.new(post_params)

        if @contender.save
           redirect_to posts_path, notice: "The contender #{@contender.name} has been uploaded."
        else
           render "new"
        end

     end

     def destroy
        @contender = contender.find(params[:id])
        @contender.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path, notice:  "The post #{@contender.name} has been deleted."
     end

      private
         def post_params
         params.require(:contender).permit(:name, :image)
      end

    private

      def contender_params
        params.require(:contender).permit(:name, :image, :post_id)
      end
end
```

**controllers/posts_controllers.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
     def index
        @posts = Post.all
     end

     def new
        @post = Post.new(params[:id])
     end

     def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        if @post.save
           redirect_to posts_path, notice: "The post #{@post.name} has been uploaded."
        else
           render "new"
        end

     end

     def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path, notice:  "The post #{@post.name} has been deleted."
     end

     private
        def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:name, :image)
     end

end
```

## Terminal

Started GET "/posts/10/contenders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-16 20:22:16 +0000
Processing by ContendersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"post_id"=>"10"}
  Rendering contenders/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Contender Load (0.5ms)
SELECT "contenders".* FROM "contenders"
  Rendered contenders/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 177ms (Views: 172.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-16 20:35:30 +0000
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Post Load (1.0ms)
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (25.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 322ms (Views: 310.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

---

**So I edited the code. And It still do not show the right thing.**

**posts/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Your poll app</h1>
            </div>
            <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <%= post.name %>
                    <br>
                    <%= post.id %>
                    <%= link_to "Contenders", post_contenders_path( post_id: post.id ) %>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="">
                     <%= image_tag post.image_url %>
                    </img>
                </a>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
</div>
```

**contenders/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h1 class="page-header">
                Test
              </h1>
            </div>
            <% @contenders.each do |contender| %>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <%= contender.name %>
                    <br>
                    <%= contender.post_id %>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="" alt="">
                     <%= image_tag contender.image_url %>
                    </img>
                </a>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
</div>
```

**controllers/contenders_controllers.rb**

```
class ContendersController < InheritedResources::Base
     def show
        @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:post_id] )
        @contenders = @post.contenders
     end

      private
         def post_params
         params.require(:contender).permit(:name, :image)
      end

    private

      def contender_params
        params.require(:contender).permit(:name, :image, :post_id)
      end
end
```

**controllers/posts_controllers.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
     def index
        @posts = Post.all
     end
     def show
       @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:post_id] )
       @contenders = @post.contenders # Assuming that they have a has_many/belongs to relationship.
     end

     private
        def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:name, :image)
     end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contenders
  resources :users
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :posts do
    resources :contenders
  end
  root "posts#index"

end
```

Comment: You terminal output shows that you're rendering from the ContenderController#index. Which has the code `@contenders = Contender.all`, so that's why it's rendering all the contenders. If you want to scope it, first find the `@post` with the `:post_id` and then call all the contenders for that post. I show this in my answer below in the `show` method. You can do the same thing in the contenders_controller index action and I'll post an edit. Give that a try. :-)

Comment: Hi James, I've updated the code. But I guess there is still something missing.. :(

Comment: Is the terminal output still the same? Can you paste the new output if it's different? Can you paste your `rake routes` output? Also, you could try making the route go to the show page. Like this `<%= link_to post_path(post.id) %>`. Did you try putting the `@post = Post.find_by(id: params[:post_id] ); @contenders = @post.contenders` code in the `contenders_controller#index`?

Comment: Wow I just tried to put the code in contenders_controller#index
and it worked ... I thought I did it before .. but maybe I didn't restart the server I don't know. Weird hahaha. But it works!!! Thanks for your help James !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a nested url, then you will need something in your routes file that looks like this:

```
# routes.rb
resources :posts do
  resources :contenders
end
```

And then in your `posts_controller` you want your `show` method to be able to be the index of `contenders` for a specific `post`, right?

So, in the show method, you'd have the controller find the post with the `:post_id` and then list the contenders for that post, like this:

```
# posts_controller.rb
def show
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:post_id] )
  @contenders = @post.contenders # Assuming that they have a has_many/belongs to relationship.
end
```

As for the view, you look like you've linked it properly. You can run `rake routes` on the command line to get the output of the routes that your application has drawn. The first column is the list of names that you can call for the route. In the third column, you'll see the url with any of the dynamic parts written like `:id` or `:post_id`, these tell you that you need to pass that information to the route.

So, if you have a url like `/posts/:post_id/contenders`, which would be your index action, you will need to have a `link_to` that looks like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  ...
  <%= link_to 'Post', post_contenders_path( post_id: post.id ) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Then, in your contenders show page you'd have something like this (using the @contenders variable above):

```
# views/contenders/show.html.erb
...
<% @contenders.each do |contender| %>
  ...
  <%= contender.name %> <!-- Or some other attribute that contender has... -->
  ...
<% end %>
...
```

Let me know how this turns out!

EDIT:

It seems you're rendering the `contenders#index` as opposed to the `post#show`. If you'd like to do it this way, then you can scope the index action for contenders to the post. Like so:

```
# controllers/contenders_controller.rb
def index
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:post_id] )
  @contenders = @post.contenders
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply James, but unfortunately it is still not working for me. 

So yes basically, I'd like to have all my posts in my main page. And when I click on a post I would like to go to the contenders page that are related to the post. 

So for example: 
Main Page : Post A, B, C, D, etc
If I click on Post B, I`ll go in a page that only shows the contenders related to post B.

I'm also having problem understanding the difference between the show and the index method. (I didn't have any show method).

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, you used  "link_to 'Post'", I wondered if it is just a typo as I suppose it should be link_to 'Contenders'.

Comment: First, a `show` page shows just shows an object and any information that you want to display about that object. In this case, we want to show a single post and that post is going to have a number of contenders associated with it. That's why in the `def show ....` method, in the posts_controller, we limit the scope to the `@post`. Then we call all the contenders associated with the post with `@post.contenders`.

Comment: Second, my impression is that we are on an index of posts. And we want to see an individual post that has many contenders associated with it. Is that not the case? You are right that it's not ideal as every post in the collection with have a link "post", so you could instead write `<%= link_to post.name, post_contenders_path(post.id)%>` The first argument of the `link_to` is just the text that the link will display, it doesn't affect functionality.

Comment: Can you post information about the error that you're receiving so that we can debug you problem?

Comment: So now, when I click on a Post I go into a page that displays every contenders, even the one that are not associated with the post I clicked on. I've added on my original post what is displayed on the terminal. I think it might help.